# React / Axios: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I can see array with objects of data "fees" perfectly but if i wanna see a single value like fees[0]?.firstFee i get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

i thought ? operator would avoid this but seems like not...

```
const [fees, setFees] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const getFees = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/feesettings', {
        headers: { Authorization: token },
      });
      setFees(res.data);
    };

    getFees();
  }, []);

  console.log(fees);
  console.log(fees[0]?.firstFee );
```

Comment: Isn't it giving you an error whenever your component is getting rendered?

Comment: Yup, but when i leave the console.log(fees[0]?.firstFee); and only log the fees then not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting an error on every render is because, you are passing no value to the state, so by default fees is undefined

```
const [fees, setFees] = useState();
```

and when you reach this line of code, you are trying to access fees[0] as if fees is an array, it is not that's why it's giving you an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```
console.log(fees[0]?.firstFee);
```

So change to this line of code,

```
const [fees, setFees] = useState([]);

if (fees.length > 1) {
    console.log(fees[0]?.firstFee);
}
```